# How to make it work that v-menu in element with hover event

Tags: vue.js, hover, vuetify.js, mouse

```
<template>
  <v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }">
    <div class="img-card">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img :src="url" alt="image of gallery" />
        <transition name="fade">
          <div class="cover" :class="{ 'cover-active': hover }">
            <v-menu offset-y>
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-text-field
                  v-bind="attrs"
                  v-on="on"
                  solo
                  append-icon="mdi-chevron-down"
                  label="Regular"
                  class="menu"
                ></v-text-field>
              </template>
              <v-list>
                <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
                  <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-menu>
            <div class="under-wrapper">
              <v-btn fab small color="#fff">
                <v-icon>mdi-upload</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn fab small color="#fff">
                <v-icon>mdi-dots-horizontal</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </div>
          </div>
        </transition>
      </div>
      <p>{{ author }}</p>
    </div>
  </v-hover>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ImgCard',
  props: ['url', 'author'],
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { title: 'Click Me' },
        { title: 'Click Me' },
        { title: 'Click Me' },
        { title: 'Click Me 2' },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.img-card {
}

.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cover {
  display: none;
  background: rgba($color: #222, $alpha: 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 16px;
}

.cover-active {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

//animation
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opcity 0.3s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

I wish make the one component like pinterest's imagee card
using Vue, Vuetify, v-menu, v-hover, mouseevnet

I thought it would work, but it's somewhat ambiguous.
'v-menu__content' is rendered outside of element and add mouse event then it worked strange.

If I add function on 'img-card' and try mouse over at drop down menu, it's disappear.. because drop down menu is outside of 'img-card'
Or it's switch on and off repeatedly.

I want to fix things that are unnatural.
Do i just give up using 'v-menu'? -_-

If my question lacks content, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps

this tooltip appears when I hover on

```
<v-tooltip top max-width="500">
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-icon v-on="on">info_outlined</v-icon>
  </template>
  <span>
    EXAMPLE TEXT
  </span>
</v-tooltip>
```